# Minimze Date in Jquery

Tags: jquery, date, formatting

```
$(".dateTime").text(Date);
```

gives the output:

> Thu Jan 23 2014 14:25:02 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

what i want:

> Thu Jan 23 2014

Is there any function for Date Only not time?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-formatting-a-date-in-javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.toDateString()`

```
var dateTimeEmelemt = $(".dateTime").text(Date.toDateString());
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/4yQwU/)

Comment: yah that works fine but if i want : Thu, Jan 23, 2014 (commas)

Comment: @Faizan then you'll have to do some .replace() on the spaces

Answer (score 0):

Use toDateString() extension method;

```
dateTimeEmelemt.toDateString()
```

The above will give Thu Jan 23 2014

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery ui date picker. it will give you all the functionality you need.

here is an axample

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Format date</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
    $( "#format" ).change(function() {
      $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", $( this ).val() );
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" size="30"></p>

<p>Format options:<br>
  <select id="format">
    <option value="mm/dd/yy">Default - mm/dd/yy</option>
    <option value="yy-mm-dd">ISO 8601 - yy-mm-dd</option>
    <option value="d M, y">Short - d M, y</option>
    <option value="d MM, y">Medium - d MM, y</option>
    <option value="DD, d MM, yy">Full - DD, d MM, yy</option>
    <option value="&apos;day&apos; d &apos;of&apos; MM &apos;in the year&apos; yy">With text - 'day' d 'of' MM 'in the year' yy</option>
  </select>
</p>


</body>
</html>
```

http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-formats

Comment: Why use jQuery datepicker? It's an unnecessary plugin to add when the function already exists in javascript

Comment: well may be it is not required in above question as your suggested anwer tells but it gives much more possibilies of formating the dates

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can do it without `Date.toDateString()` (just for fun :P)

```
var dateTimeEmelemt = $(".dateTime").text(Date);
dateTimeEmelemt = dateTimeEmelemt.split(':')[0];
var shortDateTime = dateTimeEmelemt.substr(0, dateTimeEmelemt.length - 3);
console.log(shortDateTime);
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8f84Z/)**